# Sort files according to version

Tags: linux

I have directory names with version number such as :

```
1.1.10
1.1.11
1.1.20
2.1.0
1.1.50
3.1.1
1.1.1
```

How can I sort this in following way?

```
1.1.1
1.1.10
1.1.20
1.1.50
2.1.0
3.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `sort` command does not include a `--sort=version` or `-V` option (i.e. you're in FreeBSD or OSX or you're using GNU sort earlier than version 6.0), you can sort by the individual fields, delimited by a dot.  For example:

```
$ text=$'1.1.1\n1.1.10\n1.1.20\n1.2.10\n1.1.2\n1.1.21\n1.1.12\n1.2.1\n'
$ echo "$text" | sort -t. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n
```